# Challenge: multiplyAll

Tags: javascript

Having a bit of trouble with the following task, which logs "1":

Create a **function** multiplyAll that takes an unknown number of integer arguments, multiplies them all together, and returns the result.

```js
function multiplyAll(arr){
 let product = 1;
for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    product = product * arr[i];
}
  return product;
}

console.log(multiplyAll(9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3)) // should log: 362880
console.log(multiplyAll(5, 5, 5, 3)) // should log: 375
```

Comment: `arr` is not an array. You pass multiple arguments to the function instead of an array. Change the declaration to `function multiplyAll(...arr)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way:

```js
function multiplyAll(...arr){
  return arr.reduce((m,v)=>m*v,1)
}

console.log(multiplyAll(9, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 1, 8, 3)) // should log: 362880
console.log(multiplyAll(5, 5, 5, 3)) // should log: 375
```